Ubuntu 24.04, postfix and spamassassin
I was running Ubuntu 23.04, with postfix, with spamassassin installed as a service with systemctl. At the weekend I upgraded the distro to 24.04 and have now discovered that postfix is no longer able to call spamassassin.
Originally I followed this installation guide: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/block-email-spam-check-header-body-with-postfix-spamassassin
It configures /etc/postfix/main.cf with this milter: smtpd_milters = local:spamass/spamass.sock
I now get these errors at various times:
mail:/w/serverless# cat /var/log/mail.log.1 | grep spam

Jul  6 15:33:49 mail spamass-milter[697]: spamass-milter 0.4.0 starting
Jul  6 15:34:40 mail spamass-milter[697]: Could not retrieve sendmail macro "b"!.  Please add it to confMILTER_MACROS_ENVRCPT for better spamassassin results
2024-07-06T16:10:54.054537+02:00 mail spamass-milter[816]: spamass-milter 0.4.0 starting
2024-07-06T20:45:21.391844+02:00 mail spamass-milter[816]: Could not retrieve sendmail macro "b"!.  Please add it to confMILTER_MACROS_ENVRCPT for better spamassassin results
2024-07-06T20:45:23.465636+02:00 mail spamass-milter[816]: Could not extract score from <>

2024-07-06T23:20:55.566449+02:00 mail spamc[349083]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection refused
2024-07-06T23:20:55.566535+02:00 mail spamc[349083]: connect to spamd on 127.0.0.1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection refused
2024-07-06T23:20:56.566720+02:00 mail spamc[349083]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#2 of 3): Connection refused
2024-07-06T23:20:56.566814+02:00 mail spamc[349083]: connect to spamd on 127.0.0.1 failed, retrying (#2 of 3): Connection refused
2024-07-06T23:20:57.567154+02:00 mail spamc[349083]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#3 of 3): Connection refused
2024-07-06T23:20:57.567279+02:00 mail spamc[349083]: connect to spamd on 127.0.0.1 failed, retrying (#3 of 3): Connection refused
2024-07-06T23:20:57.567368+02:00 mail spamc[349083]: connection attempt to spamd aborted after 3 retries

How can I fix this, and make postfix connect to spamassassin, when it is not running as a service?

It looks as though spamd was no longer installed after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.
Fixed by installing it:
sudo apt install spamd

/var/log/mail.log then contains:
2024-07-08T22:51:32.581538+02:00 mail spamd[2605208]: zoom: able to use 405/405 'body_0' compiled rules (100%)
2024-07-08T22:51:33.105452+02:00 mail spamd[2605208]: spamd: server started on IO::Socket::IP [::1]:783, IO::Socket::IP [127.0.0.1]:783 (running version 4.0.0)
2024-07-08T22:51:33.105808+02:00 mail spamd[2605208]: spamd: server pid: 2605208
2024-07-08T22:51:33.110974+02:00 mail spamd[2605208]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 2605234
2024-07-08T22:51:33.116192+02:00 mail spamd[2605208]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 2605235
2024-07-08T22:51:33.117151+02:00 mail spamd[2605208]: prefork: child states: IS
2024-07-08T22:51:33.117457+02:00 mail spamd[2605208]: prefork: child states: II

And when mail arrives, it is checked:
2024-07-08T22:59:12.972218+02:00 mail spamd[2605234]: spamd: connection from localhost [::1]:51148 to port 783, fd 5
...

